# Expression Builder blockSubmit Form

Tags: javascript, expressions

I am developing a script to block submition of ASI Table variable of a date, but even when the blocking is in the condition and the condtion is not engaged it still gets executed.

```
var totalRowCount = expression.getTotalRowCount();
for(var rowIndex=0; rowIndex<totalRowCount; rowIndex++){
    variable0=expression.getValue(rowIndex, "ASIT::AUDIT SUMMARY::Audit Date");
    variable1=expression.getValue(rowIndex, "ASIT::AUDIT SUMMARY::FORM");
    if(variable0.value!=null && formatDate(variable0.value,'yyyy/MM/dd') > (formatDate("31/01/2017",'yyyy/MM/dd'))){
       variable0.message="...";
       expression.setReturn(rowIndex,variable0);
       variable1.blockSubmit=true;
       expression.setReturn(rowIndex,variable1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this question by changing (rowIndex,variable1) setReturn for a Form to (variable1),it means the Form will only be blocked by condition within the Form, but not in the Audit Summary Form.

```
variable1.blockSubmit=true;
expression.setReturn(variable1);
```